# How to undelete an entity with EntityState deleted

Tags: breeze

I have an entity with a composite primary key that models a many to many relationship:

```
public class ActualAnswer
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AnsweredQuestionID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }

}
```

If I delete one of these entities in my client application using Breeze, it's state is set to Deleted:

```
function deleteEntity(entity) {
    var ea = entity.entityAspect;
    ea.setDeleted();
}
```

If the user changes their mind I currently try to recreate the entity:

```
createEntity("ActualAnswer", {
    AnsweredQuestionID: answeredquestionid,
    AnswerID: answerid
});
```

which calls this function using my Breeze `EntityManager`:

```
function createEntity(entityType, initialValues) {
    var entity = manager.createEntity(entityType, initialValues)
    return entity;
}
```

However, that causes an error:

> A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach an entity
>   when an entity with the same key is already attached:
>   ActualAnswer:#etc

It is true, we already have an entity with the same key - but it is in a "Deleted" state.

So, how can I retrieve that and undelete it?

Alternatively, can I safely use a different merge strategy? What are the pitfalls I need to look out for? Can I minimise the risk by using the merge strategy on this particular entity only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I could find to retrieve deleted items from the cache and undelete them:

```
//A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach an entity 
//when an entity with the same key is already attached
//so we need to check for deleted entities and undelete them
var queryOptions = manager.queryOptions.using({
    includeDeleted: true,
    fetchStrategy: breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache
});

var existing = EntityQuery
    .from('ActualAnswers')
    .where('AnsweredQuestionID', '==', this.ID)
    .where('AnswerID', '==', answerid)
    .using(queryOptions)
    .using(manager)
    .executeLocally();

if (existing.length > 0 && existing[0].entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
    //rejectChanges fixes navigation properties. setUnchanged doesn't
    existing[0].entityAspect.rejectChanges(); 
}
else {
    createEntity("ActualAnswer", {
        AnsweredQuestionID: this.ID,
        AnswerID: answerid
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the state to Modified instead?

```
function unDeleteEntity(entity) {
    var ea = entity.entityAspect;
    ea.setModified();
}
```

Comment: The entity models a many to many relationship. If the user removes the relationship then it should be marked for deletion on the server. If the user then recreates the relationship, it is in an unchanged state as far as the server is concerned. Nothing to modify. And this doesn't tell me how to retrieve a deleted entity in order to undelete it